# can't read $_POST data in PHP 5.6.3

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

In last few month I try to write small API using php without any framework and I face a dummy bug when I try to read `$_POST` data, I think that maybe I made dummy mistake in my code or my localhost have an issues because my code work fine when I upload it on my server, so I ignore it, now I'm working in project and I use codeigniter and I use my old code and I make some change in parameter name and etc.

After I finish everything, I try to make a test in my localhost and again when i try to read `$_post` data it always empty !!. I try to upload it on my server and it's work fine !!!

So I check my php version in my server and my localhost and I found that my server work with php 5.4 and my localhost work on 5.6.3 !

Is there any solution for this problem ? anyone face the same issue?

Example:

```
    function user_signin_post()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        //save the input in variables
        $username = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('username'));
        $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('password'));

       // form_validation all the fields are not empty
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'required');

       if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
       {
           $result = array('status' => $this->input->post(),'Error_Number' => 121,'Error_Message' => 'dont miss username fild.');
           $this->response($result);

        }else
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                 $result = array('status' => 0,'Error_Number' => 122,'Error_Message' => 'dont miss password fild.');
                 $this->response($result);

             }else
             {
                  // load the user model
                  $this->load->model('users_model');
                  $this->load->model('security_model');

                 // use the signin function
                 $query = $this->users_model->user_signin($username, $password);
                 $session_key = $this->security_model->create_user_session($query);
                 $array = array('user_id' => $query, 'session_key' => $session_key);
                 $this->response($array, 200);

           }//end 2nd if
    }//end 1st if
```

I always get:

```
{
"status": [],
"Error_Number": 121,
"Error_Message": "dont miss username fild."
 }
```

And I try to print the $_POST data and it's empty

Comment: How are you posting? via a form post or an AJAX call?

Comment: add come code to your post??

Comment: @Schien i use codeigniter so it's `$this->input->post('password')`

Comment: What about the sending part? Just a regular form? Also try $_POST in a separate test file, just to ignore any interference from CI

Comment: @Schien i make the post using rest client because i build an api

Comment: @Dagon did i say it's not a framework ?

Comment: @Dagon read my post again i say i make one api without framework and also another one with framework and i face the same thing

Answer (score 1):

You should show us some of your code with the error message.

Since you are using codeigniter as your frame work, use `$this->input->post();`
you have two options:
1- for debugging use `die(print_r($this->input->post()));` this will show all the values that have been posted.
2- use `$this->input->post('post_name');` to retrieve a single value.

Comment: it's always get `{
    "status": 0,
    "Error_Number": 121,
    "Error_Message": "dont miss username fild."
}`

Comment: @csbukhari ok, for a structured debugging process;
add `die(print_r($this->input->post()));` in the beginning of your function `function user_signin_post()
    {` before doing anything else. and show the output.